# If inside a for loop (day difference for common and leap year) not working

Tags: c, date-difference

I'm new to C-programming and I'm trying to make a code to count the day difference between a date and a birthday.

```
int year, birth_year;
int year_common;
int year_leap;

for(int i = year; i <= birth_year; i--){
  year = i;

  if (year % 400 != 0 || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0)){
      year_common++;
  }

  if(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)){
      year_leap++;
  }
}

int date_pass = (year_common * 365) + (year_leap * 366);
```

I wanted the loop to decrement the 'i', add 1 into the year_common integer when it's a common year, and add 1 into the year_leap integer when it's a leap year until it is the same as the birth_year.

For now, I'm still trying to check out the years, but no matter how many year difference I made, they always give out 5856 days.

e.g. :
birth date : 05/11/2005
checked date : 05/11/ 2007
give out '5856 days'

And I don't know where that number comes from.

I tried initializing it with 0, but it gave out 0 days instead.

I tried this code:

```
int year_pass = year - birth_year;
int year_leap = 0;

for(int i = year; i <= birth_year; i--){
    if(i % 400 == 0 || (i % 100 != 0 && i % 4 == 0)){
        year_leap++;
    }
}

int date_pass = (year_pass * 365) + (year_leap * 1);
```

And it missed 1 day for the leap year.

Is there something wrong with the loop?

My prof wants the code to be as standard as possible with loops and conditions.

Comment: Your local variables `year_common` and `year_leap` are not initialized and will have "garbage" values. They will not be zero at the beginning unless you explicitly declare them with `int year_common = 0;`

Comment: @MOehm I tried initializing it with 0, but it also gave out 0.

Comment: Hm. Okay, so you are counting down towards the birth year. The second part of the `for` loop must be true in order to execute the loop body, but `i` shouldn't be smaller the the birth year. I think the condition sould be `i >= birth_year`.

Comment: You code is strange - why the two `if`s? Year is either leap or not, you should do `if (something) { year_leap++; } else { year_not_leap++; }`. Read about DeMorgan laws.

Comment: @MOehm then it won't end till the birth year, no?

Comment: @KamilCuk just tried this. didn't work, though. it still gave out 5856 days

Comment: I assume that the (current) `year` comes after the `birth_year`, so say the current year is 2020 and the birth year is 2002. You start at 2020, but 2020 ≤ 2002 isn't true, so you don't enter the loop at all. The value 5856 cones from not initializing the variables, they apparently get the "garbage" values 0 and 16.

Comment: In your first code the two conditions are not mutual exclusive. The first condition does not properly limit to leap years. Every year is counted as leap year there.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks! It worked. It still gave out 1461 days between 3 years with 1 leap year, so I changed the loop to only count the leap year and substract it from the total year difference for the common year.

Comment: There's also the question whether you need to account for the leap day. If the person was born in June or October in a leap year, you don't "cross" Feb 29, so you don't have to consider it. The same applies to the current date: If you ask in January or February, the leap-year-ness doen't matter.

Comment: `if (year % 400 != 0 || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0))` <-- typo right here

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the year common and year leap as in variables but haven't assigned any value. Since youre adding one unit by `++;`, you need to pre define year_leap and year_common =0

```
int year, birth_year;
int year_common=0;
int year_leap=0;
```

Comment: sorry, i edited the post. i tried declaring it by 0, it gave out 0 days instead.

Comment: @Jack try redoing the whole thing, step by step, define each variable individually, assign values to all of them that need to be assigned any values and also, i don't know if you notice but you call i<=birth year, so its gotta be always smaller or equal, and then you make i--, so it will basically loop infinitely, try changing that to i++

Answer (score 0):

Dates are hard to handle, with all UTC leap seconds and local timezones - leap years are only the tip of the iceberg. Don't reinvent the wheel. Whenever you want to do something with dates, first thing to do is to convert everything to seconds since epoch. Then you do what you want.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main() {
    // 05/11/2005
    struct tm birthday = { 
        .tm_year = 2005 - 1900,
        .tm_mon = 11,
        .tm_mday = 5,
        .tm_hour = 12,
    };
    // 05/11/2007
    struct tm end = {
        .tm_year = 2007 - 1900,
        .tm_mon = 11,
        .tm_mday = 5,
        .tm_hour = 12,
    };
    time_t birth_s = mktime(&birthday);
    time_t end_s = mktime(&end);
    time_t diff_s = end_s - birth_s;
    time_t diff_day = diff_s / 3600 / 24;
    printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)diff_day);
}
```

Comment: the prof wants the code to be as standard as possible with only loops and conditions. i heard something about julian day numbers, but i don't know how that works.